# Serializing DateTime back to AJAX method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

My AJAX method returns a view model, which is a data structure serialized using `JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize()`. This data includes a number of nullable `DateTime?` properties.

It has come to my attention that these dates show up in JavaScript as a string in the format `"/Date(1480551007625)/"`. After a little research, I figured out how to convert this to a JavaScript date.

But the problem is that if I post the data back to my AJAX methods, I get the following error:

> /Date(1480551007625)/ is not a valid value for DateTime.

This error occurs even when *I haven't modified that value in the view model!* That is, I'm just posting back the exact same, unmodified view-model object.

How do I convert the DateTime properties in my view mode on the client side so that they can be posted back to the server and be converted back to `DateTime` properties.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482856/proper-way-to-convert-json-date-to-net-datetime-during-deserialization) may be of use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my surprise, this is *waaaaaaaaaay* too much trouble. So, in my view model, I changed the date fields to strings and just stored the strings in the format `"2016|12|1"`.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you need to do something like

```
serializer.Deserialize<DateTime>("/Date(1480551007625)/");
```

without the `<DateTime>`, I'd expect Deserialize to return a string and converting a string in this format to a DateTime probably doesn't work.

Comment: The error occurs when it attempts to parse the data to my C# data structures. So there is an error before my C# code even gains control here.